# Does ASTParser already give a CFG?

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm working a lot with ASTParser from Eclipse, but I cannot understand do I get an AST graph or already a CFG. If only AST, please say how it should be modified to be a CFG. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ASTParser gives you an AST from code, i.e. you get a syntax tree (yes, a graph, but with restrictions on cross and back edges).

The CFG is what you give to the parser so it knows how to parse, such as `AST.JLS3`, which instructs the parser to use the java language spec v3 grammar to perform the parsing.

Comment: Thanks a lot, is there a way to get CFG automatically? Or any instructions to build cfg from astparser?

Comment: I'm not sure what means there are to infer a grammar from an AST. In some way the grammar is encoded in the implementation of the parser, but I suppose it's about as easy as extracting any spec from an implementation. You may have more luck asking in a community more dedicated to compilers or DSLs.